# Ввод данных с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Есть программа, которая сортирует символы в строке в обратном порядке. Подскажите, как правильно сделать, чтобы строка задавалась с клавиатуры?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* str_rev(const char* ptr)
{
    int i, j;
    int sz=strlen(ptr);
    char* result=strdup(ptr);
    for(i=0, j=sz-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        char tmp=result[i];
        result[i]=result[j];
    result[j]=tmp;
}
return result;
}

int main()
{
printf("%s\n", str_rev("Privet Andrey"));
}
```

Comment: `printf`, `strlen`, `strdup`,... `[c++]`??

Comment: @Fortek, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @Fortek, мне проще всего вызывать fgets().

Comment: если это C++, то 'cin >>'

Comment: @smallFish, тогда уж [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline)